Wall Painting Issues - flashing is due to difference in texture
I'm having an issue with the paint on a small patched area on the wall, about the size of an electrical box. I used Zinsser Gardz as a primer over the fresh drywall patch, then applied two coats of Sherwin Williams Cashmere paint. However, by the end of the second coat, I noticed some flashing. I didn’t think much of it and added a third coat, but the flashing became even more noticeable.
Upon closer inspection, I believe the flashing is due to a difference in texture between some parts of the painted area and the rest of the wall. For reference, I painted the entire wall, not just the patched area. I'm not entirely sure if this is related, but the flashing seems to occur in spots with limited airflow. I've attached a picture of the setup—the wall above the washer looks fine, but the issue appears in areas that were blocked by the washer.




This may have happened because the new repaired section will draw the water out of the paint quicker than paint over old paint.  You may have not allowed enough time for the paint on the entire wall to dry.  Give it more time, (at least 48 hours) and paint another coat.
